# Android - Context argument in PendingIntent.getActivity

Tags: android, android-pendingintent, android-context

When creating a pending intent using the method `PendingIntent.getActivity()`, the first argument is (according to the android docs)

> The Context in which this PendingIntent should start the activity.

When im lanuching a new instance of an activity in my application, i can pass `getApplicationContext()`. But if i want to launch an instance of another application's activity, what should be the *context* argument ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This context is needed for `startActivity()`, so just pass what you did so far and it shall make no difference that the activiy you want to launch is in other package.

Answer (score 1):

Just this context is OK. It is similar as you launch the activity by getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent) in your app.

Answer (score 1):

You can use any `Context` you like to fire an `Intent` to another Application - Whether that be a `Service`, an `Activity` or a `Context` from `getApplicationContext()` or passed to you in a Receiver.